# AngularJS pass variable into factory

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following `select` list:

```
<select name="make" class="form-control" ng-model="selectCity">
    <option value="Kannur">Kannur</option>
    <option value="Agra">Agra</option>
    <option value="Ahemedabad">Ahemedabad</option>
    <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
    <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
    <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
</select>
```

When I change the selected option I need to pass the `ng-model`, `selectCity` into a factory which calls an `API`:

**The factory:**

```
carPriceApp.factory('APIservices', function($http){

    APIcarModels = {};
    APIcarModels.getAPIcarModels = function(){
        return $http.get('/carprices3/api/apiData'+ selectCity +'.js')
    }
    return APIcarModels;

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass variable to factory angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800891/pass-variable-to-factory-angularjs)

Comment: Where is selectCity coming from? Don't you need to put that as an argument?

Comment: @YuujinLee Its from <select ng-model="selectCity"></select>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved your problem write html here

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-change="changeCity()" name="make" class="form-control" ng-model="selectCity">
    <option value="Kannur">Kannur</option>
    <option value="Agra">Agra</option>
    <option value="Ahemedabad">Ahemedabad</option>
    <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
    <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
    <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and javascript here

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory('APIservices', function($http) {
  var APIcarModels = {};
  APIcarModels.getAPIcarModels = function(selectCity) {
    alert(selectCity);
    return $http.get('/carprices3/api/apiData'+ selectCity +'.js')
  }
  return APIcarModels;

});

function myCtrl($scope, APIservices) {
  $scope.changeCity = function() {
    APIservices.getAPIcarModels($scope.selectCity);
  };

}
```

Working example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/592/)

Comment: May i ask another question ? How can i pass $routeParams too as a argument in to factory ?

Comment: Take `$routeParams` values like respective controllers show here https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/routeparams-api  and pass like `APIservices.getAPIcarModels($routeParams.routeParamsName);`

Comment: Now not working existing argument when i implement your code , I have to pass two argument or I need find another way instead of first argument - Any idea ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78117/discussion-between-vamsikrishnamannem-and-hunter).

Comment: Ok forget $routeParams I dont need confuse you . Just think I have another  select tag too  same as we have already done  http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/593/

Comment: though in this case there is no need to pass a parameter to the factory method. 
But what about other cases where it would be logical.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ng-change` property on your select list and from there call your API.  You'll also need to take a parameter in your `getAPIcarModels` function:

Your markup would be like:

```
<select name="make" class="form-control" ng-model="selectCity" ng-change="selectMake()">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.selectMake = selectMake() {
    APIservices.getAPIcarModels($scope.selectCity);
}
```

And finally, your factory:

```
APIcarModels.getAPIcarModels = function(selectCity){
    return $http.get('/carprices3/api/apiData'+ selectCity +'.js')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add something like `ng-change="changeCity(selectCity)"`

Refer below articles for example and more information

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/0IVNLHiw3jpz4zMKcB0P?p=preview
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485346/how-do-i-get-the-ng-model-of-a-select-tag-to-get-the-initially-selected-option    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935869/id-as-ng-model-for-select-in-angularjs
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively: using `ng-options` :


view:

```
<div ng-app='App' ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedCity" ng-options="city.name for city in cities">
</select>
   Selected City is  {{selectedCity.name}}
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.cities = [
        {name: 'Chicago'},
        {name: 'London'}
     ];
    $scope.selectedCity = '';   
});
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/pz9f093e/